# A Google Form creates an Event in Google Calendar (without using responses)

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

This is more of a simple yes or no question with the hope that someone could point me in the right direction.

My company has Google Calendar and Google Forms.  What we want to do is create a Registration Form using Google Forms, once the Registration Form is created then it will automatically create an event within our Google Calendar with the Registration Form Link.

We do not want to use the responses to create an event, we want to use the form to create the event.   The responses are set up within the form to be emailed to the a specific person where they can tally and confirm all the registries.

Our company also has a wordpress site, so maybe there is a plugin for wordpress that creates the form and automatically creates an event on our Google Calendar.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is an Add-on that will take a date/time from a Form submission and create a calendar event.  [Data Director](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=1)

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Form editor you could create a bounded script project and add to it an script that creates a Google Calendar event, so yes, it's possible.